# Finding DIV's in a php | Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i am trying to findout, in which php file does the below  exists.
Reason, the href does not work on the logo1.png. in my below code.

```
<div class="site-branding">
<h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://ironware.in/" rel="home">IRONWARE</a></h1>
<p class="site-description">Home Products..</p>
</div>
```

stylesheet:

```
.site-branding {
    content: url("http://ironware.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Logo1.png");
    width: 35% !important;
```

Now to find, by browser > right click > Inspect element > in which PHP does the  exists ?

Comment: You cant. Use a program (e.g. dreamweaver) that is able to search in multiple PHP files and let it search for the syntax.

Comment: It's probably not there *literally*. Most likely the code says something like `<a href="<?=$site->getUrl()?>" rel="home"><?=$site->getTitle()?></a>` or something. Better search for a specific part that isn't likely to be generated from code, like `class="site-title"`. And of course, you have to search in the PHP source on the server, most likely in the template part (this is no core functionality). The browser only sees the complete HTML output. It is not aware of PHP, let alone of the separate PHP files.

Comment: Or you could search across files (on the server) for `<div class="site-branding">` (that part is probably in plain HTML in the PHP file without any PHP code).

Comment: check in `header.php` mostly site description is in the header if not you will see any file included

Comment: you should understand the architecture of your wordpress theme, so that you can navigate through php webpages to locate any particular code

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by adding the below to my childs theme's header.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'storefront_custom_logo' );
function storefront_custom_logo() {
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_site_branding', 20 );
    add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_display_custom_logo', 20 );
}

function storefront_display_custom_logo() {
?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" class="site-logo-link" rel="home">
        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" />
    </a>
<?php
}
```

Comment: this is not a answer to your question "Finding DIV's in a php | Wordpress", its just a particular case that you got it in header.php but this is not generalised